# How to Install steam on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, 15.04, steam

just installed ubuntu 15.04 and i cant install steam.

if i do sudo apt-get install steam

it returns E: Package 'steam' has no installation candidate

full comand and return

```
alan@alan-RF511-RF411-RF711:~$ sudo apt-get install steam
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Package steam is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  steam-launcher

E: Package 'steam' has no installation candidate
alan@alan-RF511-RF411-RF711:~$ sudo apt-get install steam-launcher
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Package steam-launcher is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Comment: Have you tried downloading and installing from here?
https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb
Then all you need is to do is `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/steam.deb`

Comment: please verify this : Open `software &Updates` -->`Ubuntu software` tab--> check `multiverse` (should be enabled)....then try again.please let me know the progress.:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
sudo gdebi steam.deb
```

Source:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve

They list a bunch of solutions and have more information available. Let us know if this worked so that others can find this more easily. Thanks.